# Android List View from Json

Tags: android, json, listview

I am very new to Android and am trying to populate a list view from a json string on my server.

I'm getting the following error:

> com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value ...of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

when trying to parse the following array:

```
[{
    "id": "7",
    "day": "Thursday",
    "offertitle": "Buy One Get One Free",
    "offerdesc": "Validity: Everyday ",
    "imagename": "bogof",
    "offercode": "none",
    "status": "YES"
}, {
    "id": "11",
    "day": "Thursday",
    "offertitle": "2-4-1 Cocktails ",
    "offerdesc": "Validity: Everyday",
    "imagename": "cocktails",
    "offercode": "none",
    "status": "YES"
}]
```

I am using this code to parse the json:

```html
     JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);

      for (int i=0; i<jsonarray.length(); i++){

  JSONObject jsonProductObject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
 String name = jsonProductObject.getString("offertitle");

  myFamily.add(name);

     }
```

Any help appreciated

Full Method:

```html
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_offers);

        final String PREFS_NAME = "userDefaults";
        final ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewOffers);

        SharedPreferences settings_get = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String smartCode2 = settings_get.getString("smartCode2", "");

        final ArrayList<String> myFamily = new ArrayList<>();

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(offers.this);
        String url = "http://www.barfibrenetwork.co.uk/backend/androidoffers.php?smartcode="+smartCode2;
// Request a string response from the provided URL.



        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.i("Response: ", response.toString());



                        try {

                            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);

                            for (int i=0; i<jsonarray.length(); i++){

                                JSONObject jsonProductObject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String name = jsonProductObject.getString("offertitle");

                                myFamily.add(name);

                            }



                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.i("volley Request", error.toString());


                    }
                });
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.

        queue.add(jsObjRequest);

        Log.i("REPLY:", myFamily.toString());


        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myFamily);
        myListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);




    }
```

Full LogCat:

> 03-09 21:01:11.529 12696-12696/com.**** I/volley Request: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"id":"7","day":"Thursday","offertitle":"Buy One Get One Free (12pm-8pm)","offerdesc":"Validity: Everyday 12pm-8pm when you show this page at the bar. Which ever drink you buy you get the same drink for free. Some product lines are excluded from this promotion. Excludes certain dates at manages discretion.","imagename":"bogof","offercode":"none","status":"YES"},{"id":"11","day":"Thursday","offertitle":"2-4-1 Cocktails ","offerdesc":"Validity: Everyday 5-8pm when you show this page at the bar. Which ever drink you buy you get the same drink for free. Included Cocktails indicated with *. Excludes certain dates at manages discretion.","imagename":"cocktails","offercode":"none","status":"YES"},{"id":"18","day":"Thursday","offertitle":"Wine of the Week £21","offerdesc":"Validity: Everyday on the selected wine of the week. Please ask staff for details Excludes certain dates at manages discretion.","imagename":"wine","offercode":"none","status":"YES"},{"id":"25","day":"Thursday","offertitle":"Unlimited Coffee £5","offerdesc":"Validity: But one coffee for £5 and get unlimited coffee before 7pm. Valid once per customer per day. Non transferable.","imagename":"coffee","offercode":"none","status":"YES"},{"id":"32","day":"Thursday","offertitle":"Single Vodka Redbull £5","offerdesc":"Validity: 7 days a week, all day, all night. Smirnoff Vodka only, cannot be used in conjunction with any other offer.","imagename":"redbull","offercode":"none","status":"YES"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Are you sure that JSON is correct? `new JSONArray(response);` should be fine

Comment: Hi, yes i'm pretty sure its correct, I edited it slightly to make it easier to read but here is the url I am pulling it from: http://www.barfibrenetwork.co.uk/backend/andriodoffers.php

Comment: your code is woring well 
if you print the myFamily you will get 
[Buy One Get One Free, 2-4-1 Cocktails ]

Comment: Show the full logcat and method definitions please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using JsonObjectRequest but there is no JSONObject in your json.

Give this a try.
I hope it helps :D

Code:

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
     if (response != null) {
         try {
             for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                 JSONObject jsonProductObject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                 String name = jsonProductObject.getString("offertitle");
                 myFamily.add(name);
             }
         } catch (JSONException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
}}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
      @Override
      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
           Log.i("volley Request", error.toString());
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Volley` Library is  **deprecated** my advice is to switch to `OkHttp` Library instead
of `Volley`
See an Example, this Method takes an Url and Fetch Json Response.

```
public static String JsonResponse(URL url) throws IOException {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.body().string();
}
```

**Note:**
This Library worked in the Main Thread so you should use `AsyncTask`

**Update**

See the official Repository [Here](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)